# PrimeFaces how to change attribute of @ManagedBean from xhtml

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm wondering if is it possible to change the value of an attribute

I tried this but it does not work:

```
<p:menuitem value="ADD" action="#{a.setA2("NewA2Value")}"/>
```

Assume that I have this @ManagedBean class:

```
@ManagedBean
public class A {
 private String a1;
 private String a2;

 public A() {
 }

 public void setA1(String a1) {
  this.a1 = a1;
 }

 public void setA2(String a2) {
  this.a2 = a2;
 }

 public String getA1() {
  return a1;
 }

 public String getA2() {
  return a2;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options here.

1. **Method expression**
2. **f:setPropertyActionListener**
3. **f:atribute**
4. **f:param**

> Take a look to this: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

Example with **f:setPropertyActionListener**

```
<p:menuitem value="ADD" action="#{a.myAction}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{a.a1}" value="myValue" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{a.a2}" value="myValue2" />
</p:menuitem>
```

Don't forget the **h:form**

And your action should looks like this.

```
public String myAction() {
  //String value = this.a1;
  //String value2 = this.a2;
  //You have to return the viewId for the navigation, or null
}
```

or

```
public void myAction() {
  //String value = this.a1;
  //String value2 = this.a2;
}
```